# Infinite loop despite reaching break condition

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
unsigned int calcFact(int input)
{
    int flag = 0;
    int temp = input-1;
    int i;
    unsigned int factorial = input;

    for(;;)
    {
        factorial = factorial * temp;
        temp = temp - 1;
        printf("%d\n",temp);
        if(temp == 1)
        {
            printf("%d\n",temp);
            break;
        }
    }

    return (factorial);
}
```

As you can see, it is a simple program to calculate the factorial of the input. However, it never breaks out of the loop. temp becomes 1 (I've checked with the first print statement). However, the second statement never prints which means it never enters the if condition. This is very puzzling.

I did this another way and got what I wanted. However, I was wondering if there is something fundamental about C that is causing an error here?

EDIT: Changed the order. I had moved things around a lot and I screwed it up. The point remains. Regardless, the loop never breaks

Regardless of where the print statement is, it won't change the fact that the loop never breaks. That was the real problem. May be I didn't make it as clear. I'm using the print statement simply for debugging. It still continues on in the loop. Temp becomes 2...1...0 and then -2^16.

Comment: The second statement won't print, as you break it before printing.

Answer (score 2):

In your exit condition, `break;` is called before `printf("%d\n",temp)` meaning that it will break out of the for loop before executing that statement.

Saying ".. the second statement never prints which means it never enters the if condition" is incorrect because it does indeed enter the if condition, you just don't know about it. Put `break;` after `printf` and you will see.